# HTTP referer headers - mobile browsers

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, mobile-browser

I seem to have a unique problem. In my apache logs (for a mobile site)  I see that for some requests the referer header is null ("-"). All requests on the logs are "href" links and occur from a mobile browser by clicking/tapping . So there is almost no chance of the url being accessed from the address bar directly (in which case I can understand the absence of a  referer header) . What are the other possibilities that a referer header can be null ?

Are there mobile devices which have a browser feature to turn of referer headers (like desktop browsers) ?

I also understand that such a thing can be achieved on a desktop browser by spoofing the the UserAgent to a mobile device. But I'm slightly hesitant as there is no motive for the user to do so.

Also, will the referer header persist when a link is opened in a separate window/tab ? (Again, I'm not sure if this is possible on a mobile device)

Any thoughts will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

most newer mobile browsers support opening in new window/tab ... in that case the referrer is lost...
referrer can also be blank in case of a redirect ... if the redirecting page had no referrer